# Specify number of characters in each line in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

Hey, Is it possible to specify a textview to have 25 characters in a line? I have tried     android:maxLength="25" though it shows the first part of the text and the other part disappears.. Thanks

Edit1: I can also put the text into an EditText.. but I want that the characters that are after 25 chars, go to a new line..

Comment: I don't think this is possible, and if it were it would break Android's ability to intelligently fit your UI to different display sizes / densities / form-factors.

Comment: Since its a textview and you control the text that goes in it, why don't you either limit the length of the text to 25 characters when you set the value? or insert a newline char every 25th character?

Comment: @jkhouw1 I thought there would be a more efficient way to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , sure `android:maxLength="5"` works for TextView to set the maximum number of characters for TextView. You can set `android:layout_width="130dip"` for the TextView too. That will show the character in the format abc... if the text exceed the layout width.

Comment: I dont want to show "abc..." , I want the text gets displayed to a new line not into "..."

Comment: then set a fixed width in android:layout_width  and also use **android:singleline="false"**. It will automatically start in the next line when the limit will exceed. Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLength

I am afraid, maxLength works for input EditText only. :-(